# Malloc and double issue

Tags: c, double, malloc

I have created a dynamic vector using malloc, if I create it using entire numbers there is no problem, but once I use double like in the code I got wrong answers, instead of printing 35 and 88.5 I got 0 and 0, does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    double * dd;
    dd = malloc(2*sizeof(double*));

    dd[0] = 35;
    dd[1] = 88.5;

    printf(" %d ",dd[0]);
    printf(" %d ",dd[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't allocate dynamically?

Comment: `double*` is a pointer type. And it's size is not necessarily the same as of `double`

Comment: `%d` is for integral numbers. Use `%lf` for double (long float)

Comment: "Float" in the title is a little misleading, because float is a different type than double.

Comment: `dd = malloc(2*sizeof(double*));` => `dd = malloc(2*sizeof(double));`  will dynamically allocate space to hold two `doubles`.

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez `%f` is more than enough, `%f` is for printing doubles

Comment: Avoid coding errors, allocate to the size of the dereferenced pointer, not to the type: `dd = malloc(sizeof *dd * 2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems with your code

```
dd = malloc(2*sizeof(double*));
```

this is allocating space for 2 `double` pointers, you should use
`sizeof(double)` or even better do it like this:

```
dd = malloc(2 * sizeof *dd);
if(dd == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // do not continue
}
```

The second problem is that `%d` is the convertion specifier for `int`, you are
passing doubles, this yields undefined behaviour. You have to use `%f`

```
printf(" %f\n", dd[0]);
printf(" %f\n", dd[1]);
```

> *man 3 printf*
>
> **Conversion specifiers**
>
> **d**, **i**: The  `int`  argument is converted to signed decimal notation.  The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must
>   appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros.  The default precision is 1.  When  0
>   is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.
>
> ...
>
> **f**, **F**: The  `double`  argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style `[-]ddd.ddd`, where the number of digits after the
>   decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.  If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;
>   if  the  precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears.  If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

And don't forget to free the memory with

```
free(dd);
```

So your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    double * dd;
    dd = malloc(2 * sizeof *dd);
    if(dd == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    dd[0] = 35;
    dd[1] = 88.5;

    printf(" %f\n", dd[0]);
    printf(" %f\n", dd[1]);

    free(dd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format specifiers for printing.

The `%d` format specifier to `printf` expects a `int`, but you're passing in a `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as printing the wrong values.

To print a `double`, you need `%f`:

```
printf(" %f ",dd[0]);
printf(" %f ",dd[1]);
```

Also, you're not allocating the correct amount of size for your array.  You need space for 2 `double`, but you allocate space for 2 `double *`.  So change the expression to get the size of a `double`:

```
dd = malloc(2*sizeof(double));
```